How do I handle logical errors in kotlin arrow
I'm working on a function where there is more than one possible failure path that I need to differentiate between. My paths are

success - return the value
logical error - non-fatal issue that the can be recovered from
exception - unexpected error that should be bubbled up

I found the arrow documentation here: https://arrow-kt.io/learn/typed-errors/working-with-typed-errors/ and read through it, but I'm still struggling to understand how to actually apply the information.
If I have some code like the following:
fun doValidation():Either<Error,String>
{
    val v1 = "123abc"
    val v2 = "abc"
    val v3 = "1234"
    validateName(v1)
    validateName(v2)
    validateName(v3)
}

fun validateName( value:String):Either<Error,String>
{
    if(value.length < 4)
    {
        //this is an unexpected exception
        return Error("$value has less than 4 characters").left()
    }
    else if(value.contains("abc"))
    {
        //this is a logical failure that we can recover from
        //this will not compile as-written
       return value.left()
    }
    else
    {
        return (value + "_xyz").right()
    }
}

what is the idiomatic way to implement validateName() such that doValidation can detect and recover from logical errors while still bubbling exceptions up the call stack?

Unexpected errors should be thrown as an exception so that they can be bubbled up the call stack. Expected errors (aka logical errors) are returned as the left part of your Either:
fun validateName(value: String): Either<Error, String> = when {
    value.length < 4 -> throw IllegalArgumentException("$value has less than 4 characters")
    value.contains("abc") -> Error("$value contains abc").left()
    else -> (value + "_xyz").right()
}

